# How do you use the CustomRoomData on Appwarps with cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, appwarp

Just started coding with Appwarps and I'm running into an issue.  I have a lobby built that shows live rooms, but I really do not want to show the rooms for matches that have already started.  I figured I would use

```
void Client::setCustomRoomData(std::string roomId, std::string customData)
```

But I have some doubts on how to use it.  Once the game starts, I plan on sending

```
SetCustomRoomData(roomId, "Closed");
```

to notify the server that open seating is now closed.  However, when I check the room properties on another device when it calls

```
void CCAppwarpDelegate::onGetLiveRoomInfoDone(AppWarp::liveroom revent)
{
CCLog("CustomData=%s",revent.customData.c_str());
...
```

it returns blank.  What am I missing here?  Besides the code not working, what really makes me question myself is that I don't understand the mechanics of the properties.  How do you have multiple custom properties since you aren't assigning it any kind of index...or do room only have a single custom property at any given time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use customData and instead use only room properties. Room properties is a set of key/value pairs that you can associate with a room.

I recommend you read the following link 
http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/matchmaking-basic-concept/

So the flow is as follows -

1. you first create the room using the createRoom API and pass a
   properties dictionary containing <"closed", "false">.
2. Then once the game is active, you use updateRoomProperties API
       on the room and pass <"closed", "true"> to the API.
3. Then when you want to show the list you should use
       getRoomWithProperties and pass <"closed", "false">. This will get
       you a list of rooms that are not yet "closed".

Comment: So these are set via code and not using the appwarp dashboard?  I think that's where my disconnect has been.  Thank you for the info!